# Out of Memory Error Downloading Large File with TIdFTP

Tags: memory, ftp, indy

I am trying to download a video file from an FTP server using TIdFTP (version 10.6.2.5366).

I can establish the connection and start to download the file, but after a while - I am guessing around 500MB, it throws and "Out of Memory" error.

After setting

```
ADataChannel.IOHandler.LargeStream := True
```

in the IdFTPDataChannelCreate procedure, my code is simply:-

```
with IdFTP do
  begin
    TransferType := ftBinary;
    Get(Filename, DestinationFolder + '\' + ShortFilename, True, False); 
  end;
```

Am I missing something?  Are there other properties I need to set to get this to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `LargeStream` has no effect on `TIdFTP`, as the file size is not sent before the file data (besides, `TIdFTP` sets `LargeStream=True` for you). I don't see how this code can raise an "out of memory" error as there is very little memory being used. You are using the version of `Get()` that downloads directly to the file system via `TFileStream` (well, `TIdFileCreateStream`). `TIdFTP` will read the file data from the socket in `TIdFTP.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize` chunks (32K by default) and write them as-is to the `TFileStream`. There is a little more overhead if compression is used, but not much.

Comment: What does the call stack look like exactly when the error is raised?

Comment: I managed to get myself completely confused over this.  I had trimmed my code snippet and omitted the bit that was causing the problem.  Fixed now.  But thanks for the comment - it was helpful

Comment: And what was the problem exactly? Since it is not part of your original question, the question can't be answered as-is, so either update it or close it.